# php script calling parent javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have this folder structure:

```
index.php

js/scripts.js
```

In `index.php` I have a JavaScript function defined called `execute()`.

Now within `index.php` I have a form that when submitted will call `email.php` and at the end of the execution of the `email.php` I do this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">parent.execute();</script>';
```

This all works fine.

Now when I move `execute()` into `scripts.js` and I put this line of code in `index.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

then `email.php` is somehow unable to find `execute()` function. I know this because if I modify the execute function only the original version (the one that was in index.php) is ran.

I know this is weird, but I am new to this and I don't know of anyway I can debug this. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: if you're moving it to the js file why not just call the function at the end of the email.php file, `<script>execute();</script>`? you won't need to do any scoping like `parent` in that case

Comment: Debug by hitting f12 in your browser and setting a breakpoint.

Comment: how will email.php know where to find execute()?

Comment: the form is sumited into an iframe yes

Comment: What's the contents of `.scripts.js`?

Comment: Does `execute` exist in both script.js and index.php simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you don't have a typo in your `<script>` tag.  You've referred to your external script file as both script.js and scripts.js.  One little 's' can make all the difference.

Assuming you've included your script correctly, most likely, you have put `execute` within another function, thus taking it out of the global scope.  That would be the case if script.js looks something like this:

```
(function () {
    ...
    function execute () {
        ...
    }
})();
```

If that's the case, move `execute` out of it's containing function.  You can also put `execute` in the global scope by explicitly making it a property of `window`:

```
window.execute = function execute () {
    ...
};
```

If you do it this way, it's fine to leave `execute` within another function.